# Is there a way to allow only certain type of widgets in the sidebars?

Tags: wordpress, widget, sidebar

For example, I want Sidebar A to display nothing but one text widget and Sidebar B to display anything but text widgets. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In it's current form, your question is very broad. To get a positive response here, it's best if you show what you have tried. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just make two files `sidebarA.php` and `sidebarB.php` and include both files in your `page.php`

In Sidebar A:

```
 <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("your_text_widget")  ) : ?>
```

In sidebar B:

```
<?php  if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("your_widgets1")  ) : ?>
<?php  if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("your_widgets2")  ) : ?>
<?php  if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("your_widgets")  ) : ?>
```